# Remove end of timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, substring, gsub, stringr

I have a vector of timestamps with whose `"+00"` I would like to remove

```
> test
[1] "2018-01-02 06:40:00+00" "2018-01-02 06:50:00+00" "2018-01-02 07:00:00+00"
[4] "2018-01-02 07:10:00+00" "2018-01-02 07:20:00+00" "2018-01-02 07:30:00+00"
```

They are already in character class

```
> class(test)
[1] "character"
```

And I have applied `gsub()`

```
> gsub("+.*","",test)
[1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

But this does not provide the desired output - what am I doing wrong?

```
dput(test)
c("2018-01-02 06:40:00+00", "2018-01-02 06:50:00+00", "2018-01-02 07:00:00+00", 
"2018-01-02 07:10:00+00", "2018-01-02 07:20:00+00", "2018-01-02 07:30:00+00")
```

Comment: You have to escape the + sign: `sub("\\+.*","",test)`. It has a special meaning in regular expressions. Also note that in order to convert to POSIXct, you don't need to remove those parts of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract everything BUT the `+00`. Using `$` makes regex fit the pattern to the very last part of the string.

```
> gsub("(^.*)\\+00$", "\\1", x) # extract everything between ()
[1] "2018-01-02 06:40:00" "2018-01-02 06:50:00" "2018-01-02 07:00:00"
[4] "2018-01-02 07:10:00" "2018-01-02 07:20:00" "2018-01-02 07:30:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by first turning your character vector into a POSIXct element, and then converting this back to a character.

```
> test <- c("2018-01-02 06:40:00+00","2018-01-02 06:50:00+00","2018-01-02   07:00:00+00")
> test_date <- as.POSIXct(test, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> test_char <- as.character(test_date)
> test_char
[1] "2018-01-02 06:40:00" "2018-01-02 06:50:00" "2018-01-02 07:00:00"
```

The advantage is that you can modify the syntax of the timestamp freely:

```
> test_char_2 <- as.character(format(test_date, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
> test_char_2
[1] "01/02/18 06:40:00" "01/02/18 06:50:00" "01/02/18 07:00:00"
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

If number of characters are the same, just use *substr*:

```
test <- c("2018-01-02 06:40:00+00", "2018-01-02 06:50:00+00", "2018-01-02 07:00:00+00")

nchar(test)
# [1] 22 22 22

substr(test, 1, 19)
# [1] "2018-01-02 06:40:00" "2018-01-02 06:50:00" "2018-01-02 07:00:00"
```

Or use *gsub* with *fixed = TRUE*:

```
gsub("+00", "", test, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "2018-01-02 06:40:00" "2018-01-02 06:50:00" "2018-01-02 07:00:00"
```